# ¿Cómo sumar propiedades de objetos que a su vez pertenecen a un array? JS

Tags: javascript, javascript-objeto

Tengo este problema: La funcion 'checkInventario' recibe como argumento un array de objetos llamado 'inventario' y el nombre de un item llamado 'item'
Cada objeto tiene una propiedad 'nombre' y 'cantidad'.
La funcion debe devolver la cantidad de items que hay.
Si el item no existe la funcion tiene que devolver 0 (cero).
Ej:

```
var inventario = [
   {    nombre: 'tenedor',
       cantidad: 6
     },
    {
       nombre: 'cuchara',
       cantidad: 4,
     },
   ]
   checkInventario(inventario, 'tenedor') devuelve => 6
   Tu código aca:
```

Lo que yo hice fue esto:

```
function checkInventario(inventario, item) {
for (i = 0; i < inventario.length; i++) {
    if (inventario[i].nombre === item) {
      return inventario[i].cantidad;
    } else {
      return 0;
    }
  }
}
```

Me salta error me pasa la cantidad de tenedores pero no de "cuchara".

Comment: Ayudaría mucho que agregues que error obtienes

Comment: El `return 0;` debería estar al salir del ciclo y eliminar la parte del `else`, porque ahora solo analizas el primer elemento y si no coincide, devuelves cero en lugar de seguir recorriendo el arreglo.

Comment: si lo puse al final me da la cantidad de en mi caso "tenedores" y no de "cuchara"

Answer (score 2):

```js
function checkInventario(inventario, item) {
    return inventario.find((e)=> e.nombre === item )?.cantidad || 0;
}

var inventario = [
   {    nombre: 'tenedor',
       cantidad: 6
     },
    {
       nombre: 'cuchara',
       cantidad: 4,
     },
];
console.log(checkInventario(inventario, 'tenedor')); //6
console.log(checkInventario(inventario, 'vaso')); //0
```

solo tener en cuenta que al validar te valida por mayusculas minusculas y pudieses usar un tipo

```js
function checkInventario(inventario, item) {
    return inventario.find((e)=> e.nombre.toString().toLowerCase() === item.toString().toLowerCase() )?.cantidad || 0;
}

var inventario = [
   {    nombre: 'tenedor',
       cantidad: 6
     },
    {
       nombre: 'cuchara',
       cantidad: 4,
     },
];

console.log(checkInventario(inventario, 'Tenedor')); //6
console.log(checkInventario(inventario, 'Vaso')); //0
```

[Array.prototype.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/find)

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas sacar el `return 0` fuera del bucle asi:

```
function checkInventario(inventario, item) {
  for (i = 0; i < inventario.length; i++) {
    if (inventario[i].nombre === item) {
      return inventario[i].cantidad;
    } 
  }
  return 0;
}
```

De lo contrario si el item que buscas no esta en la primera posicion siempre va a retornar 0;

Comment: Ayudaría que le expliques que diferencia hace tener o no ese return 0

Answer (score 0):

//Esto es lo que buscas:

```
for (i = 0; i < inventario.length; i++) {
  if (inventario[i].nombre === item) {
    return inventario[i].cantidad;
  } 
  else{
    return 0;
  }
}
```

}

Comment: Bienvenido/a a [es.so]: haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. Debes explicar brevemente lo que hace este código: ten en cuenta que la respuesta debe ser útil no solo para el OP, sino para los demás miembros de la comunidad. _Este sitio no es un repositorio de código_. Lee [answer].